# Simple samba configuration for write access to usb drive (raspbian)

Tags: debian, samba, raspbian

I have been trying for hours getting an NTFS usb drive shared from a raspberry with raspbian to a WIndows 8 PC over ethernet, via samba.

I don't care about security, I want to be able to share my drive on my lan, seems very simple to me... My device is /dev/sda1 and it is mounted on /media/Data

Last config I tried:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = SambaServer
security = share
name resolve order = hosts lmhosts


[Media]
path = /media/Data
force user = root
force group = root
read only = no
guest ok = yes
```

Works for READING but not for WRITING.
I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't a samba problem, but the USB drive was read-only, I had to install ntfs-3g and mount it with it.

Mounting drives as read only by default... I love linux...